# Create folder in Save dialog - can't enter uppercase letters or underscore

Tags: dialog

I have a long standing problem with the Save dialog in Chromium or Libreoffice (and many more applications using the system Save dialog). In the Save dialog, there is a button Create folder on the right. When clicked, I am asked to "Type name of new folder". However, if I use uppercase letters or undescore in the name of the folder, a line for entering new folder name immediately disappears. As a consequence, I can't create folders from this dialog containing uppercase or undescore.

I have this issue on current Ubuntu 16.04, but had it before also on Ubuntu 15.10. I have absolutely no clue what may be causing this behavior and how to prevent it. My Google search was also not successfull.

Any help is very appreciated.

Daniel